# How to prove orthogonality of "generalized cross product"

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I'm looking for a proof that if $v_1, ..., v_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $\wedge (v_1, ..., v_{n-1})$ is orthogonal to each $v_1, ..., v_{n-1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

[image]

Comment: You don't need the hypothesis that the $v_i$ are orthogonal among each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote down is just a mnemonic for the formula giving the coordinates of the generalised cross product with respect to a positively oriented orthonormal basis $\def\e#1{\mathbf e_{#1}}\e1.\ldots,\e n$; it is not a definition, worse, the formula is not defined in any formal sense (since a determinant has to have all its entries in some commutative ring to be defined, which is not the case here).

For a proper definition, one could start with an Euclidean space$~V$ of dimension$~n>0$. The space of $n$-linear alternating forms on$~V$ has dimension$~1$, and each nonzero such form when applied to ordered orthonormal bases of$~V$ takes exactly two (opposite) values, partitioning the set of ordered orthonormal bases into two parts. Choosing one part as the "positively oriented" among these bases makes $V$ into an oriented Euclidean space, and singles out among the $n$-linear alternating forms the one, to be called the volume form$\def\vol{\operatorname{vol}{}}~\vol$ of$~V$, that takes the value$~1$ on the positively oriented orthonormal bases.

Now fixing $n-1$ vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}\in V$, the map $V\to\Bbb R$ given by $w\mapsto\vol(v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1},w)$ is a linear form on$~V$. Then there is a unique vector$~u$ such that the map coincides with $w\mapsto u\cdot w$, and by definition $\bigwedge(v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1})=u$; in other words one has the defining relation
$$
  \vol(v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1},w)=\bigwedge(v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1})\cdot w
\qquad\text{for all $w\in V$.}
$$

The fact that to volume form vanishes when its arguments are linearly dependent (as does any alternating multilinear form) here means that $\bigwedge(v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1})$ is orthogonal to any vector in the span of $v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1}$, and in particular to each of the $v_i$ themselves.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was a weird formula too and wondered where it came from. Can you recommend a material on this subject? I have no idea what alternating- or linear forms are.

Comment: Also, how would one go about constructing an explicit formula for $\wedge$ using the definition above?

Answer (score 1):

The dot product of that vector with a vector $w$ is obtained by replacing the last row of that formal determinant with the coordinates of $w$.